# Make .each() only run once per .text()

Tags: jquery, each

Title might be a bit misleading.. But I will try to explain it better.

```
$('.class').each(function(){
    username = $(this).text();
    alert(username);
});
```

On this page we have a span-tag with the class "class". Is is possible to make it alert only the first time the username appears on the page? For instance, if the same username appears 10 times on the page, I do not want it to alert the username 10 times, but only the first time.

Is that possible? Pseudo-kinda code:

```
if username appears more than once
    alert username once
```

Thanks

Comment: Simply store the usernames you previously saw in an object used as map.

Comment: Care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Or just build an array and add the usernames as you encounter them. If the username is in the array, don't alert it.

Comment: @Snorlax I made an answer so that it's clearer.

Comment: Wumpus: That is not what I am asking. I need it to alert each username on the page, but if the same username appears twice, then ignore those. Only display each username once.

Comment: When and how to you know that the text is the username?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a vote down... I haven't seen anyone explain this before on Stackoverflow. Have you guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a case, the idea is to use an object as a map to store the usernames you previously saw :

```
var seen = {};
$('.class').each(function(){
    username = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (seen[username]) return;
    alert(username);
    seen[username] = 1;
});
```

Note that it's frequent in HTML to have unwanted spaces around your texts, mainly new lines. That's why I used `$.trim`.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot. I will mark it as answer when I can! :)